# call URL inside get() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok. I have the following jQuery code

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery.get('/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=1234', {}, function(data) { 
galleryXML = data;
renderGallery(pageIndex);
}, "xml");          
});
```

As you can see, I have 1 URL (`'/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=147'`) which I display it in “GalleryView.html”. 
Now I want to show another URL/ID in the same page like so (`'/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=258'`).

Can I add the url beside each other like so

```
jQuery.get('/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=1234', 
'/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=1234', {}, function(data) {
```

How can I display 2 URL in the same get() function????

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot put two url's in jquery's get.

You could always nest the two gets... I'm assuming here that you want to render two pages of gallery on one page...

```
var galleryTemp;
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery.get('/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=1234', {}, function(data) { 
    galleryTemp = data;
    jQuery.get('/GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=2345', {}, function(data) { 
      galleryXML = data;
      $(galleryXML).prepend($(galleryTemp).children());
      renderGallery(pageIndex);
  }, "xml");              
});
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a good solution for you off the top of my head for loading N pages...

Answer (score 0):

yes JBristow, you got my Q right :)

Ok may  be i forget to add the following code in my Q.

```
jQuery('#placeholderGallery').empty();
jQuery(jQuery(html)).appendTo('#placeholderGallery');
```

Where (#placeholderGallery) contains the media gallery which i want to repeat adding it when ever i have new one.

so what i did is, comment the first line [`jQuery('#placeholderGallery').empty();`]
, and then repeat my first entry as following:

```
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.get('GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=369', {}, function(data) { 
            galleryXML = data;
            renderGallery(pageIndex);
        }, "xml");          
    }); 
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.get('GalleryPage.aspx?gallery=365', {}, function(data) { 
            galleryXML = data;
            renderGallery(pageIndex);
        }, "xml");          
    });
```

Hope this helps, and thanks guys for your help :)